# Enough to call Children.Clear on a WPF canvas to get rid of old controls before adding new ones?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, children, slowdown

I am experimenting with WPF and re-implementing my old maze screensaver.

My code basically adds a bunch of images to the canvas, building up a grid, 64x64 pixel images side by side, to cover the entire canvas. Then I "animate" movement in the maze, which is supposed to scroll the maze around, by adjusting a translate transformation, and swapping out the images.

However, it seems I have a leak of some sort. Whenever I resize the window, I want to re-build the image components in order to cover the form again, either with more or fewer images.

If I drag the lower left corner of the form around in tight circles the rebuild part gets slower and slower.

To remove the old controls I simply did this:

```
_Canvas.Children.Clear();
```

is this enough? Due to the slowdown I assume it isn't.

However, since the maze is currently not "discovered" by the "avatar", the maze images are drawn with 25% opacity, and I would assume that if I failed to remove them, I would get many images on top of each other, but it doesn't appear to be that either.

I am caching the image sources, the image components are created like this:

```
_Images = new Image[(int)width, (int)height];
for (int x = -1; x < width - 1; x++)
{
    for (int y = -1; y < height - 1; y++)
    {
        Image i = new Image();
        i.Width = 64;
        i.Height = 64;
        i.Source = _Outside;
        Canvas.SetLeft(i, x * 64);
        Canvas.SetTop(i, y * 64);
        _Canvas.Children.Add(i);
        _Images[x + 1, y + 1] = i;
    }
}
```

Afterwards they're assigned images to show like this:

```
Maze.Square sq = _Maze[_TopLeftMazeX + x, _TopLeftMazeY + y];
Image img = _Images[x + 1, y + 1];

if (sq.Seen)
    img.Opacity = 1.0;
else
    img.Opacity = 0.25;
switch (sq.Type)
{
    case Maze.SquareType.Hallway:
        img.Source = _Hallway;
        break;

    case Maze.SquareType.Wall:
        img.Source = _Wall;
        break;

    case Maze.SquareType.Outside:
        img.Source = _Outside;
        break;
}
```

What else should I look for? Is there a need to dispose of the image components in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `_Canvas.Children.Clear();` will remove all references to the images from the visual tree, so there are no leaks there. You may want to check for old image references being held in `_Images`, or some other collection you might be maintaining. For instance, you said that you were caching the image sources - doing this inefficiently, or maintaining an ever-growing list of stale images will definitely impact your system.

Comment: The _Images field is just an array, re-created each time I rebuild the controls, and the sources aren't reloaded after the program has loaded them once, so to me it doesn't appear to be either of those that could be the culprit. But thanks for clearing up that .Clear really is enough to get rid of the old controls. It isn't that part at least.